# How are Makefile variables calculated?

Tags: makefile, escaping

I'm new to using Makefiles & am puzzled by something…

I have the following in a Makefile…

```
USER_ID := $(id -u)
USER_ID_ESC := $$(id -u)

MAKEFILE := $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
ROOT_DIR := $(dir $(MAKEFILE))


x:
    echo $${USER_ID}
    echo ${USER_ID}
    echo $(USER_ID)
    echo $${USER_ID_ESC}
    echo ${USER_ID_ESC}
    echo $(USER_ID_ESC)
    echo $${ROOT_DIR}
    echo ${ROOT_DIR}
    echo $(ROOT_DIR)
    exit 0
```

Which give the output…

```
echo ${USER_ID}

echo

echo

echo ${USER_ID_ESC}

echo $(id -u)
502
echo $(id -u)
502
echo ${ROOT_DIR}

echo /Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/commissioning-tool-api/
/Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/commissioning-tool-api/
echo /Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/commissioning-tool-api/
/Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/commissioning-tool-api/
exit 0
```

I understand the use of double `$` to escape the use of `$`, but what I don't understand why using a single `$` for `realpath` & `dir` commands works, but using it for the `id` command doesn't.

Can someone help me out in understanding?

Thanks

Comment: `realpath` and `dir` are `GNU make` functions, `id` isn't. If you want to use a shell function inside a Makefile, use `$(shell id -u)`. `realpath` and `sir` aren't escaped, they are correctly interpreted by `GNU make`

Comment: Thanks @TimF Care to add that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Sure, I've done it and added some more details and links :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realpath` and `dir` are `GNU make` functions, `id` isn't. If you want to use a shell function inside a Makefile, use `$(shell id -u)`. `realpath` and `dir` aren't escaped, they are correctly interpreted by GNU make.

See [GNU make file name functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) as well as [GNU make shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) manual pages.

When you write `$(id -u)` in a Makefile, `make` will try to look if it's a function or a variable, and since it's none of these it will not expand to anything, hence the empty `echo`s.

Now the reason why your ID was correctly written when you did escape the dollar sign is mysterious and probably due to your shell. What happened is that `make` didn't try to expand it since the `$` is escaped, so `echo $(id -u)` was sent to the system. You can try it directly in your shell, you should obtain the same result.